# Is there a way to pass option file for rake db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

After migrating to Rails 5, I found that schema.rb has extra changes such as  `options` parameter which adds information about the database used for generating the schema.

```
create_table "student", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci" do |t|
  t.integer "admission_id"
end
```

We run our RSpec unit tests using SQLite3 on Jenkins which has been working smooth. But after the upgrade, the schema change is now database specific and this fails our test on Jenkins.

I want to generate two different schema file (test_schema.rb, schema.rb), one for test and another for production environment. Is there a way to pass schema file while running rake db:schema:load.

Example:

```
rake db:schema:load --schema-file test_schema.rb
```

I would also appreciate if anyone could share about how to use two different database. I know it's not a good practice to run test and production using different database.

Comment: As an aside, `rake` commands are unified under `rails` now. e.g. `rails generate migration ...`, `rails db:migrate`, `rails server`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

[Github rails/rails - Rails 5 schema.rb adding non-agnostic options. dev mysql -> test sqlite](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/26209) might be of interest (open and seemingly with no solution at time of writing).

I think Rails really wants the schema.rb to be agnostic with little ability to have seperate schemas, but there are issues and I guess few people actually use multiple database vendors in one project.

Best suggestion I really have is to git ignore the `schema.rb` itself, then just copy/rename DB specific ones before and after running the relevant `rails db:*` commands.

Comment: Git ignoring makes sense in my case :)

Comment: Might be an idea to also reply in rails/rails. I also just realised that since you mentioned SQLite3 specifically the foriegn key issue as well would potentially burn you. You really want foreign keys at the DB level unless you want all the extra effort of worring about every relation possibily being nil, and orphan child records, etc. because of race conditions with ActiveRecord. But schema.rb from SQLite drops them if your not careful, even though modern SQLite has foreign key support.